# HTML form with 2 steps

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form, let's say it's like this (it's actually more complicated, but let's just say it's like this):

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li class="step1 step_selected">Step 1. Enter Your Information</li>
        <li class="step2">STEP 2. Fine Print</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="step1">
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{0,20}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Your First Name')"  onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"/>

        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{0,20}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Your Last Name')"  onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"/>

        <input id="continue" name="" type="button" value="CONTINUE TO NEXT STEP" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="step2" style="display:none">
        <p>All characters appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.</p>
        <input name="" type="submit" value="I understand" />    
    </div>
</form>
```

I want the form to do basic HTML5 validation on the form when "#continue" is clicked and not allow a click unless the pattern matches, even though it's not a submit button.

If the pattern matches I want it to:

1. display:none ".step1"
2. display:block ".step2"
3. change the "step1 stepselected" to "step1"
4. change the "step2" to "step2 stepselected"

What's the simplest way to do this and am I doing this the wrong way entirely and I need to be using jquery validation?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2334rhfy/4/

Comment: Hey this is perfect, put it as an answer and I can give you the check mark!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var $listep = $('li.step_selected');
  if ($listep.hasClass('step1')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    $('#firstName, #lastName').each(function() {
      if (!this.validity.valid) {
        valid = false;
        return false;
      }
    })
    if (valid) {
      $('div.step1').hide();
      $('div.step2').show();
      $('li.step1').removeClass('step_selected');
      $('li.step2').addClass('step_selected');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.step_selected {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li class="step1 step_selected">Step 1. Enter Your Information</li>
    <li class="step2">STEP 2. Fine Print</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="step1">
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{0,20}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Your First Name')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />

    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{0,20}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Your Last Name')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />

    <input id="continue" name="" type="submit" value="CONTINUE TO NEXT STEP" />
  </div>

  <div class="step2" style="display:none">
    <p>All characters appearing in this work are fictitious. Any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.</p>
    <input name="" type="submit" value="I understand" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2334rhfy/)

Comment: In this fiddle, the error message doesn't appear when I try to submit an empty field. Also, in reality there are multiple fields, I took them out for simplicity's sake. I guess I should add them back in because I realize now it's relevant.